# In android how do I convert my setter value to a string?

Tags: java, android, tostring, getter-setter

In my activity I have `sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB(obj.getString("username"));`

It sets the value to a `string` from my `DB` and then I get that value in my `adapter` for use in my `recyclerView`, which is working ok.

In my activity how can I convert `sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB(obj.getString("username"));` to a string?

I've tried the below but it doesn't work:

```
String userNameAsString= String.valueOf(sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB(obj.getString("username")));
```

and

```
String phoneNoonPhone = (sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB(obj.getString("username")).toString());
```

It tells me the method `toString can't be resolved` and `Cannot resolve method valueOf(void);`

Comment: Whats the return type of `sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB()` ? If it returns void, which would make sense for setter method, than I do not see what is the endgame here... Even if you could find a way to achieve that you'll always get the same value...

Comment: The end game is I have another setter, `sharedReview.setNameFromPhone()`, which is a name in phone contacts. I have all `names` and `numbers` in phone contacts as a `json array` So if the phone number in contacts equals `sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB()` then I want to grab the matching name and set it to `sharedReview.setNameFromPhone()` which will come up in my recyclerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long shot:

```
String phoneNoonPhone = obj.getString("username");
sharedReview.setPhoneNumberofUserFromDB(phoneNoonPhone);
```

In general setters return `void` (nothing), so you don't actually get something to assign to a variable from the return. Getters *do* return something. Generally for every `void setFoo(Type t)` there would be a `Type getFoo()`. In your case I'd expect a `String getPhoneNumberofUserFromDB()`.